# How do I remove an existing class name and add a new one with jQuery and cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

How can you remove a class name and replace it with a new one?

```
<style>
    .red {background-color: #FF0000;}
    .green{background-color: #00FF00;}
    .blue {background-color: #0000FF;}
</style>

<body class="red">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">red</a></li>
        <li><a href="">green</a></li>
        <li><a href="">blue</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

In this case when you click on red or green or blue, the body class name will change accordingly. Also it will make a cookie which will save the choice.

I tried the jQuery .addClass and it's working, but it's adding a class on top of the existing one. Also I can't manage to save the cookie.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use:

```
$('.red').removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
```

[Here's the full working code](http://jsbin.com/ugufi):

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var color = $(this).text();
        $("body").removeClass().addClass(color);
        return false;
    });
});
```

And now for the cookie part

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var color = $(this).text();
        $("body").removeClass().addClass(color);
        createCookie("color",color);
        return false;
    });

    if (readCookie("color") != null) {
      $("body").removeClass().addClass(readCookie("color"));

    }
    else {
      $("body").removeClass().addClass("red");
    }
});

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else
        var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ')
                c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
                return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

[Working example here](http://jsbin.com/usucu). A thank you to [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for the pre-made cookie code (cookie-cutter cookie code?)

Comment: i tried that but since the cookie value will replace that class name its not working.

Comment: thank you very much. this works perfectly.

now for the cookie part. is there any other way to save without cookie plugin

Answer (score 4):

Without jQuery you can do this with a line as simple as:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className = "red";
```

This effectively removes the class assigned to the element and replace it with whatever you want.

For cookies, [PPK has a few simple methods to read/write/erase cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

```
createCookie("mySiteCookie", "red", 7); // Set the cookie to expire in 7 days.
readCookie("mySiteCookie"); // Should yield "red"
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need [removeClass](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/removeClass#class).