# how to save class name in cookies by using jquery?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I don't want to change current choose class after page loaded. So, how to save class name in cookies?
**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:" class="red-btn">red</a>
<a href="javascript:" class="green-btn">green</a>
<!-- Result -->
<div class="red" >Testing Text1</div>
<div class="red" >Testing Text2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click',".red-btn",function (){
        alert("red color");
        jQuery(".green").removeClass("green").addClass("red");
    });
    jQuery(document).on('click',".green-btn",function (){
        alert("green color");
        jQuery(".red").removeClass("red").addClass("green");
    });
});
```

[**My Project DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h5mk2dsb/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: Plz , explain with my demo.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove existing class name and add a new one with jQuery and Cookies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804584/how-to-remove-existing-class-name-and-add-a-new-one-with-jquery-and-cookies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the jQuery cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

The usage in your example is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //check if cookie has been set
    var cookieColor = $.cookie("selected_class");
    if (cookieColor) {
          //remove default "red" class and add cookie class
          $(".red").removeClass("red").addClass(cookieColor);
    }

    jQuery(document).on('click',".red-btn",function (){
        alert("red color");
         //store the value
         $.cookie("selected_class", "red");

        jQuery(".green").removeClass("green").addClass("red");
    });
    jQuery(document).on('click',".green-btn",function (){
        alert("green color");

         //store the value
         $.cookie("selected_class", "green");
        jQuery(".red").removeClass("red").addClass("green");
    });
});
```

Comment: When i choose green class, red class is to change green class but green class not remain after page loaded. http://jsfiddle.net/h5mk2dsb/1/

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake in the first line....
It must be
var cookieColor = $.cookie("selected_class");
Instead of "selected_color"

Comment: Ok. I get it by removing extra code (') beside selected_class.

Comment: Plz Suggest !. I not get it chrome , safari and opera browser. I get is firefox only.Why ?

Comment: Are you testing on your own machine i.e. on localhost? Because some browsers won't accept cookies from localhost. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335244/why-does-chrome-ignore-local-jquery-cookies

Comment: Yes, I test my project on localhost?

Comment: At least for Chrome, the easiest workaround is using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" as host name.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[class*=btn]').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('.red-btn'))
    {
        $(".green").removeClass("green").addClass("red");
        $.cookie("color-class", "red");
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('.green-btn'))
    {
        $(".red").removeClass("red").addClass("green");
        $.cookie("color-class", "green");
    }
});
```